# jquery jstree plugin ; how to insert node via json?

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I am using jquery jstree plugin . I can create a jstree with json ( it has its own json plugin).  Once a initial tree is created , I want to insert more nodes . I have a subtree (in json ) to be insert .

I tried :

`var ret = jQuery.jstree.reference("#myContainer")._parse_json(subTreeJson, -1, true);`

It does not insert my subtree , but it returned a jquery object (that seems to be the generated dom ).

I then tried `$("#myContainer").jstree("move_node" , ret , -1 , "inside", true,  true, false);`

It does not insert the dom too! 
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The following can be used to add a new node.

```
$.jstree._reference('#myContainer')
    .create_node(
        '<selector of existing node>', 'after', 
        { state: 'open', data: 'My new node' }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#DestTree").jstree("delete_node", $("> li", $("#DestTree").jstree("get_container_ul")));
    var retDom = jQuery.jstree._reference("#DestTree")._parse_json( workingJson , -1 , true);
    $("#DestTree").jstree("move_node" , retDom , -1 , "after", false,  false, true);
```

Finally , the above code work for me.